# How can i restrict user to upload abusive content wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, plugins, multisite

for now i am making posts and products display as draft through it post and product will not display in frontend but is there a way to completely restirct user while he upload content.

```
             add_action('init', 'make_editor_post_drafted');

            function make_editor_post_drafted(){

            $user = wp_get_current_user();

             if ( in_array( 'editor', (array) $user->roles ) ) {

             $user_ID = get_current_user_id();   

               $users_query = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type' => array('product','post'),
                'meta_value' =>  $user_ID,
            ) );

            if ( $users_query->have_posts() ): 

                while ( $users_query->have_posts() ): $users_query->the_post();

                     wp_update_post( array('ID' => get_the_id() , 'post_status'   =>  'draft' ));   

                 endwhile; 

             endif;


            } //end if

            } //end function
```

Comment: If you want to prevent spam, try jetPack plugin. If you want to just edit your code and don't insert the post at all then just delete the post once its detected as abusive. So instead of `wp_update_post` use `wp_delete_post`

Comment: but the question is how i know that user inserted a abusive post.

Comment: it depend on how you want to implement it. May be you create an array of abusive words and search the post_content if it contains any of those words. If true then potentially those could be abusive.